# Изменение свойства объекта из массива NSArray

Tags: objective-c

Помогите решить такую заковырку по C-objective:

```
NSArray *views = @[ view1, view2 ];
```

Это я создаю массив с UIView экранами, соответственно 0 - view1, 1 - view2.
Как мне получить доступ из массива к изменению свойства hidden этих объектов, зная только индекс.
Например:
Индекс - 0. Должен вызываться view1. 
Без массива:

```
view1.hidden=NO;
```

А мой вопрос, как сделать такую же штуку, только с массивом и индексом 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы приняли предыдущий мой ответ на свой предыдущий вопрос, и мы так и не выяснили, какой именно и в точности код вы там пытаетесь исполнить у себя. Решение вашего вопроса простое, просто у меня подозрение, что вы что-то не то там у себя делаете. В любом случае, вот решение:

```
NSArray *views = @[ view1, view2 ];

UIView *yourView = (UIView *)[views objectAtIndex:0]; // это будет view1
yourView.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: вот теперь спасибо - я просто не совсем понял - где приходит индекс в массив.